# Add a column to the data frame doing element wise operation

Tags: python, pandas

Basically, pandas can copy the column by

```py
df['B'] = df['A'] + 1
```

Now, I have a column of strings and I want to add a column whose values are the lengths of each string. For example,

```
A.      B
"hello" 5
"hi"    2
```

Is it possible to add B without looping?

Comment: please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.len`:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.len()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map(len)`:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map(len)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to get the length of column

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(len)

A.      B
"hello" 5
"hi"    2
```